# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException xmlserializer

Tags: java, android, xml-serialization, indexoutofboundsexception, xmlserializer

I have a code that creates a kml file using `XMLserializer`. It works fine creating the different polygons, but I'm having an error with closing the xml that I really don't understand.

```
02-09 10:03:02.919 24712-26301/com.example.accgps W/System.err: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=24; index=-3
02-09 10:03:02.919 24712-26301/com.example.accgps W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer.endTag(KXmlSerializer.java:493)
02-09 10:03:02.919 24712-26301/com.example.accgps W/System.err:     at com.example.accgps.KMLHelper.SerialEnd(KMLHelper.java:150)
02-09 10:03:02.919 24712-26301/com.example.accgps W/System.err:     at com.example.accgps.RefreshKML$1.run(RefreshKML.java:283)
02-09 10:03:02.919 24712-26301/com.example.accgps W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)*
```

The call to the `SerialEnd()` is done after creating the polygons, which work fine, so I don't know why it is out of bounds:

```
        for (s = 0; s < PolyArray.size(); s++) {
            polygon = PolyArray.get(s);
            kH.SerialPlacePol("Tramo " + i, polygon);
            i++;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "RefreshKML: se han creado " + (i - 1) + " tramos");
        editor.putInt("poligonos", i);
        editor.apply();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No existen datos suficientes para "+
        "generar el archivo KML",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "RefreshKML: No hay datos de GPS suficientes");
}

if (end) { //Solo cierra el archivo si se termina la recopilación de datos
    kH.SerialEnd();
    end = false; //En caso de que no se completó esta opción
    copyAllFiles();
}
```

The error is provoked in the first line of the `SerialEnd()` method:

```
public void SerialEnd () {
    try{
        serializer.endTag(null,"Document"); //THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE ERROR
        serializer.endTag(null,"kml");
        //serializer.endDocument();
        //serializer.flush();
        fileos.close();
        Log.d(TAG,"KMLHelper: SerialEnd cierra archivo KML");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,"KMLHelper: Exception occured in SerialEnd");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have tried to find an answer in other questions, but I didn't find the proper solution, maybe the serializer is **closed**, but I haven't done that yet

This is how I create the `XMLserializer`, in case you see a problem in here:

```
public KMLHelper(File file) {
    try{
        serializer.endTag(null, "Document");
        serializer.endTag(null, "kml");
        serializer.endDocument();
        serializer.flush();
        Log.d(TAG,"KMLHelper: SerialEnd cierra archivo KML");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,"KMLHelper: Exception occurred in SerialEnd");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {fileos.close();} catch (IOException io) {io.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Edit: I have made some changes in the `SerialEnd()`, put the closure of the file in the finally and uncommented the endDocument method. I've also controlled the access to the thread that creates the xml file with a synchronized to the creation of the intent that is controlling the creation of the XML file with all the polygons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The problem was that it was creating 2 XMLserializer working on the same file. I changed how the service calls the method, now I'm using a background Thread to make the calls and I control the execution with a join(), so there is only 1 execution at a time.